# Recoding factor levels into fewer categories

Tags: r

There are 290 levels in a factor variable, from which I would like to extract a few (maybe 5 or 6) in order to be able to visualize data per category.

I am sure there is a function that can do the job a lot more efficiently.

Please help!

PS: No code should look like this.

```
Recoder <- c("Victim succombs to Trauma-related Death",
             "Victim succombs to Intentional Violence",
             "Victim succombs to an Accidental Death",
             "Victim succombs to Harsh Weather Conditions",
             "Unknown way to which victim succombed")

temp$reduced_nlevels_death <- if_else(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"asp"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"blun"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"deh"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"drow"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"exc"),Recoder[2],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"exp"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"fel"),Recoder[3],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"hars"),Recoder[4],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"exp"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"hit"),Recoder[3],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"hyp"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"murd"),Recoder[2],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"pres"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"shot"),Recoder[2],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"sick"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"star"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"suff"),Recoder[1],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"unk"),Recoder[5],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"veh"),Recoder[3],
                              ifelse(startsWith(temp$cause_of_death,"vio"),Recoder[2],
                              "Other"))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Something like this: http://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_collapse.html ?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!  And yes the "less horrifying" joke is completely warranted so touché!